# Route keyboard through only /dev/ttys000 on Mac OS X

Tags: osx, usb, hid

I have a USB RFID reader which acts as a HID - pretending to be a keyboard. If a card/tag gets close it 'types' `01234567890\n` (ie. the tag's code followed by a newline) straight into the active application, as any keyboard should.

I can capture the output from this device easily by tailing `/dev/ttys000`, but Mac OS X still writes those characters to the foremost application.

Is there any way to *exclusively* capture that tty or otherways disable the device in the UI, so that I can have my RFID reader output routed only to my scripts?

*Bonus brownie points if you have code that can create the exclusive lock programatically, rather than installing additional software to route the keyboard.*

Comment: This will probably require an OSX-specific solution, so apple.stackexchange.com might be a better place to post.

Comment: Good idea. I know it's frowned upon, but I've cross posted there, and I'll keep this question up to date with any progress. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205085/route-keyboard-through-only-dev-ttys000-on-mac-os-x

Comment: It's generally preferred to flag your question for migration.